# Why/When does erl give a Warning: obsolete message?

Tags: erlang, erl

I have the following code in **list.erl**:

```
-module(list).
-export([average/1]).

average(X) when list(X) -> sum(X) / len(X).

sum([H|T]) -> H + sum(T);
sum([]) -> 0.

len([_|T]) -> 1 + len(T);
len([]) -> 0.
```

Loading this module in the **erl** shell gives a Warning message.

```
Erlang R16B03 (erts-5.10.4) [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V5.10.4  (abort with ^G)
1> c(list).
list.erl:4: Warning: list/1 obsolete
{ok,list}
2>
```

When/Why does this happen? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use at guard `is_list(X)`.

```
-module(list).
-export([average/1]).

average(X) when is_list(X) -> sum(X) / len(X).

sum([H|T]) -> H + sum(T);
sum([]) -> 0.

len([_|T]) -> 1 + len(T);
len([]) -> 0.
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it. I was following [this](http://www.erlang.org/course/sequential_programming.html#listtrav) and searching for this error didn't help.

Comment: I guess that in earlier versions of Erlang Guard was list(), and left for compatibility, but is deprecated.

Comment: That is indeed the case.